# SharePoint Column validation settings - multiple fields

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server

I am using the validations settings in SharePoint 2013.
I have 3 columns

- [Arrival time at workplace]
- [Departure time from workplace]
- [VISITOR Card No]

my requirement is

```
if [VISITOR Card No] == 0  then [Arrival time at workplace] must be less than [Departure time from workplace]
```

I tried the below formula but it is not working

```
=IF([VISITOR Card No]=0,IF([Arrival time at workplace]<=[Departure time from workplace],TRUE,FALSE),TRUE)
```

Comment: I got it working Please check the below formula  removed the nested IF
=IF([VISITOR Card No]< 1,AND([Arrival time at workplace]<=[Departure time from workplace]),TRUE)

Answer (score 1):

Try the below formula

```
 =IF([VISITOR Card No]=0,AND([Arrival time at workplace]<=[Departure time from workplace]),TRUE)
```

Answer (score 0):

I got it working Please check the below formula removed the nested IF:

```
=IF([VISITOR Card No]< 1,AND([Arrival time at workplace]<=[Departure time from workplace]),TRUE)
```